# PDOException::("SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '2020-09' for column 'expiry_date' at row 1")

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando guardar en la base de datos solo el año y el mes que recibo desde el frontend para la fecha de expiración de una tarjeta de crédito. Estoy usando Laravel, mi código es el siguiente:

Migrations:

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('credit_cards', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('owner_name');
            $table->string('card_number')->unique();
            $table->char('cvv', 3);
            $table->date('expiry_date');
            $table->integer('gamer_id');
            $table->timestamp('create_at')->default(\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
            $table->timestamp('update_at')->default(\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('credit_cards');
    }
}
```

Seed:

```
<?php


use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class CreditCardSeeder extends Seeder
{

    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {

       

        DB::table('credit_cards')->insert([
            'owner_name' => 'Juan Carlos Pandolfi',
            'card_number' => '4832 4578 6541 6529',
            'cvv' => '127',
            'expiry_date' => Carbon::parse()->format('Y-m'),
            'gamer_id' => 1,
            'create_at' => Carbon::now(new \DateTimeZone('America/Panama')),
            'update_at' => Carbon::now(new \DateTimeZone('America/Panama')),
        ]);
    }
}
```

El error que recibo es el siguiente:

> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '2020-09' for column 'expiry_date' at row 1")

Alguna sugerencia? Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes guardar una fecha sin dia , ya que estas usando un campo de tipo date (podrias hacerlo en un campo varchar pero no tendria significancia en tiempo)

Te sugiero guardarlo usando un dia predeterminado (01)

```
'expiry_date' => Carbon::parse()->format('Y-m-01'),
```

El valor del dia para efectos practicos puede no tener significado, pero debe haber un dia especificado.

Luego Si deseas obtener solo el mes y año del campo fecha puedes usar la funcion MySql [`EXTRACT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract)  o `DATE_FORMAT` (ej: `2020-09-01` a `202009`)

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH from expiry_date) FROM credit_cards;
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(expiry_date,'%Y%m') FROM credit_cards;
```